# .Htaccess mod_rewrite: many RewriteCond to many RewriteRules for Drupal

Tags: .htaccess, drupal, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm in drupal and trying to redirect requests when they want a png file (e.x `image.png`), when i add this rules in end of `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` nothing affected.

**Original htaccess :**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
  # Rewrite URLs of the form 'x' to the form 'index.php?q=x'.
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

**My additional rules :**

```
  #
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} image.png$ [NC]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$ 
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://192.168.1.101/trackback
```

something ignoring/overwrite my rules i guess.

Comment: What are you exactly trying to here:  `RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$` 
  `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://192.168.1.101/trackback`

Comment: not important ! just want to redirect ! i don't know who get this post -1 ! he can't understand question and just give -1 !

Comment: See, if you want a proper answer we will need details! Are you trying to redirect to `http://192.168.1.101/trackback` when requested for `image.png` when without a `referer`?

Comment: You know ! i just append a rewrite rule in end of others, when somebody request `image.png` i want to htaccess redirect it to a php file in http://192.168.1.101/trackback/`\index.php`

Comment: your rules seem fine. where are they present? are there any other rewrite rules?

Comment: no , nothing , i have php project that get all request abd redirect them to a php files , now i want to port it to drupal module , but something wrong with htaccess i guss :-?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you added your rules *below* the existing Drupal rewriting rules. But notice the `[L, QSA]` part in the Drupal rewriting - the 'L' indicates that this should be the last rule to process, *if the conditions match*. So as long as there is no 'image.png' at the top level of your document root, the Drupal rule will match and trigger a redirect before your rules are even processed.

Try to move your additions *above* the Drupal block.